# What is the distribution of the ratio of two Poisson random variables?

Tags: random-variable, poisson-distribution

I have a question concerning random variables. Let us assume that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let's say $X$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda_1$, and $Y$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda_2$.

When you build the fracture from $X/Y$ and call this a random variable $Z$, how is this distributed and what is the mean? Is it $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$?

Comment: I just happened to come across this when looking for references. Inference for Poisson ratio is quite straightforward, for frequentists ([Nelson, 1970, "Confidence Intervals for the Ratio of Two Poisson Means and Poisson Predictor Intervals"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5216388/?reload=true)) and Bayesians alike (Lindley, 1965). No problem with zero denominators either!

Comment: The original questioner, and others, may be interested to note that $X/(Y+1)$ has expectation value $(\lambda_1/\lambda_2) (1-e^{-\lambda_2})$. Depending on your application this may be of greater use than $X/Y$. For more details see my paper in the Journal of Analytical Atomic Spectrometry, **28**, 52, called " Statistical bias in isotope ratios" w/ DOI:10.1039/C2JA10205F.

Comment: This is a frequently encountered problem in Astronomy. The Bayesian solution was worked out by Park et al. (2006, Astrophysical Journal, v652, 610-628, [Bayesian Estimation of Hardness Ratios: Modeling and Computations](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006ApJ...652..610P)). They include background contamination in their treatment.

Comment: From the abstract it is not obvious that they are dealing with the OP's question. How does this paper relate to the distribution of the ratio of two Poisson random variables?

Comment: It deals with the ratio of photon counts observed in two disjoint passbands, where both numerator and denominator are independently distributed as Poisson.  The observed ratio is modeled as the ratio of intensities, and the distribution of the intensities ratio is worked out both numerically and via MCMC.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the actual solution here, in addition to the link you've already provided.

Comment: Ah, it is too elaborate, plus no closed form solution is provided.  There is a publicly available pdf if you follow the link above.  http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/652/1/610/pdf/64399.web.pdf

Comment: https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/ttu-ir/bitstream/handle/2346/59954/31295007034522.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 15):

I think you're going to have a problem with that.   Because variable Y will have zero's, X/Y will have some undefined values such that you won't get a distribution.

Comment: +1 That's right.  But (to head off possible confusion) the problem isn't just that $Y$ can equal $0$: it's that it can equal $0$ *with positive probability.*  (For instance, a quotient of normals does have a distribution even though the denominator can equal $0$.)  Thus, $X/Y$ is undefined with positive probability, making its mean (and any other moment) undefined as well.

Comment: +1, but in the literature on false discovery rates people have no problem with $X/Y$ where $X$ is the true positives and $Y$ is the total number of positives :-). It is always understood, by convention, that 0 out of 0 equals 0.

Comment: hmm ok lets put it that way: X is a poisson distributed random variable. Y is only observed if it is 1 or bigger. But Y is poisson distributed. For example you count the games that a player has done for your favorite hockey team and you call this random variable Y. So the counts have to be bigger than one. For example you might say Y is poison distributed with mean Y+1, so there is no way for 0 counts. What does this mean to the problem that I've mentioned above? Is Z poisson distributed? And what is its mean?

Comment: @Mark: It's probably better to ask that as a new question, and to get real specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @NRH In your case there is a strong dependence of $X$ on $Y$.  That completely changes things, because now the probability of a positive:zero ratio is nil.

Comment: @whuber, that's of course right. Thanks for pointing that out. I was just thinking that maybe there was some unstated convention to make the problem meaningful. But from @MarkDollar's comment above it seems that that was not the case to begin with.

Comment: I guess you could always work with the distribution of (X+1)/(Y+1) or something like that as a suitable approximation, no? Similar things are done for the ratio of two binomial proportions, see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531405?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Or work with the ratio of two zero-truncated Poisson distributions, if it's OK to ignore the possibility of ever getting zero...

Comment: The distribution of X/(X+Y) may be more useful. It gives the proportion of X events out of all events. We avoid division by 0 except 0/0 which means that the ratio of no events is undefined.

Answer (score 12):

By realizing that the ratio is in fact not a well defined measurable set, we redefine the ratio as a properly measurable set
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{Y} \leq r \right] := \mathbb{P}\left[X \leq r Y\right]\\
= \sum_{y = 0}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^{\left\lfloor ry \right\rfloor} \frac{\lambda_{2}^y }{y!}e^{-\lambda_2} \frac{\lambda_{1}^x }{x!}e^{-\lambda_1}
$$
where the summation follows as long as $r > 0$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson variables. The density follows from the Radon-Nykodym theorem.

Comment: Suppose that $Y$ comes from a zero-truncated Poisson distribution. Would the answer then be: